# PHP / FPDF: Create table with colspan

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I want to generate a report to PDF from the Mysql database. But my big problem is, I don't know how to design the tables. I need colspan to do the table. Can anyone help? I want to make the fpdf table be like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>

        table , td, th {
            border: 1px solid #595959;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td, th {
            padding: 3px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        th {
            background: #f0e6cc;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<table width = "100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Project Team Overtime Report</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width ="30%">Team</td>
            <td width ="70%">Koh Kain Chong</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">Workers Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width ="30%">12345</td>
            <td width ="70%">Abdul Razak</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width ="30%">678910</td>
            <td width ="70%">Ahmed Albab</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width ="30%">101112</td>
            <td width ="70%">Joshua Ting</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego already solve. I try by my self. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try wkhtmltopdf (which is actually rendering your html as a browser). FPDF breaks tables.